# SVN Externals From Local Repository to Remote Repository

Tags: svn

I have a project hosted on `svn://foo.com`.

I want to use an `svn:external` file from a local repository. I want others who checkout a working copy to also download the external files. What do I need to add to the `svn:externals` file (in my wc) to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by a local repository here? Is there any other SVN repo? or you want to add an external reference to the current project? please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

So, you want that people who checkout your project also retrieve your external file.
Using command line, on a Linux distribution, I would do that:

```
cd path/to/my/wc
svn propedit svn:externals .
```

svn will launch your favorite editor here, with a buffer open containing the current contents of the svn:externals property.You can add multiple values to a property easily here by entering one value per line.

According to your example, I would append to this buffer:

```
myExternalFileName svn://foo.com/myExternalFileName
```

Finally, you just have to commit your changes:

```
svn ci . -m "Edited svn:externals... My wonderful message"
```